# need help understanding ngRepeat with filter

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to figure out what this ng-repeat line of code is doing,

```
<div ng-repeat="user in filtered = (main.users | candidate: main.filterBy)">
```

I understand that the line below will simply create a div for all the users in main.users

```
<div ng-repeat="user in main.users">
```

What is the first example doing? I assume theres some filter going on but it doesn't resemble the syntax of any filter examples I see in the angular docs

Comment: I don't know why the person who wrote the code added the "filtered=". That's unnecessary and may break the code. It looks like there's a custom filter named "candidate" that is filtering somehow based on main.filterBy. This could be tightened up by just using the filterFilter.

Comment: In the rest of my template.html I'm not seeing filtered being used elsewhere, is it therefore unnecessary? I'm not seeing any other filtered scope variable in my controller or view, so would I be able to just simplify it to just 

<div ng-repeat="user in main.users | candidate: main.filterBy)">

Comment: That's the first thing I would try :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the above syntax does filtering `main.users` by `candidate` filter by passing `main.filterBy` value to that filter by using this line `(main.users | candidate: main.filterBy)` and the result of this is getting stored in `filtered` variable. So each time when digest cycle fires up you will see the `filtered` value updated.

Official refactored and semantic syntax is here

```
<div ng-repeat="user in main.users | candidate: main.filterBy as filtered">
```

which clearly says that you can have filtered result in `filtered` scope variable which is used as alias of that output.

[**Sample Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/O3pTOk4ITMi15ZjGotr9?p=preview)

Comment: In the rest of my template.html I'm not seeing filtered being used elsewhere, is it therefore unnecessary? I see in your Plunker you do use your as results with ng-if="results.length == 0", but I'm not seeing any other filtered scope variable in my controller or view, so would I be able to just simplify it to

<div ng-repeat="user in main.users | candidate: main.filterBy)">

Comment: Yes...if its not used anywhere else then you should remove that part..but yes if you wanted to show filtered list count then this thing could help you..